# Airmon-ng fails to create monitor interface

Tags: 10.10, wireless

When I try to start airmon-ng, I get the following output

```
# airmon-ng start wlan0

Found 5 processes that could cause trouble.
If airodump-ng, aireplay-ng or airtun-ng stops working after
a short period of time, you may want to kill (some of) them!

PID     Name
993     avahi-daemon
994     NetworkManager
999     avahi-daemon
1539    wpa_supplicant
4568    dhclient
Process with PID 4568 (dhclient) is running on interface wlan0


Interface   Chipset     Driver

wlan0       Broadcom    b43 - [phy0]
```

When I kill those processes with

```
kill -9 993 994 999 1539 4568
```

it doesn't help. airodump-ng and aireplay-ng won't work.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check, whether your device is supported. See the [list of supported devices](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=b43).